# Transfer between Page and Web control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

There are `test.aspx` page and `test.ascx` web user control.

I have a button in `test.aspx =  btn_test` and above code in my button is :

```
 Dim ct As Control = Page.LoadControl("test.ascx")
 Panel1.Controls.Add(ct)
```

There is a dropdownlist with value 1 to 10 in `test.aspx` and there is `label_test` in `test.ascx`

I need some code when `test.ascx` loading, get `dropdownlist.selectedvalue` and show it in `label_test`.

Please help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to implement this. One you could try would be to cast the test.ascx web control being loaded like so (replace TestControl with the class name for the control):

```
Dim ct As TestControl = CType(Page.LoadControl("test.ascx"), TestControl)
```

And then create a public property in the control which you would use to set the value from the DropDownList.

```
Dim ct As TestControl = CType(Page.LoadControl("test.ascx"), TestControl)
ct.DropDownListValue = DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value
Panel1.Controls.Add(ct)
```

This property would then be used to set the labels value (either directly using the set accessor or via a method within the test.ascx control).